# Como chamar uma função JS pelo Bean JSF passando parâmetro assim que a pagina é carregada?

Tags: javascript, jsf, aplicação-web

Eu tenho que chamar uma função no meu JS passando como parâmetro um vetor, quando a página for carregada.

Eu consigo fazer isso usando um `p:commandButton`, onde aqui: `actionListener="#{rotaEntregaBean.gerarMapa()}"` eu executo a função no Bean (pegando valores no banco de dados) e depois, `aqui:oncomplete="initMap(xhr, status, args)"` eu executo a função JS.

**Botão**

```
<p:commandButton id="btnMapa" value="Gerar Rota" icon="ui-icon-pin-s" 
 actionListener="#{rotaEntregaBean.gerarMapa()}"
 style="float:right" oncomplete="initMap(xhr, status, args)"/>
```

**Bean**

[image: Bean]

Mas estou querendo fazer isso sem ser preciso o click do botão, assim que carregar a pagina.
Na minha pagina eu já inicio um método do Bean como mostra a imagem abaixo, mas não sei chamar a função JS com parâmetro.

Chamando método Bean assim que a pagina é carregada:

```
<f:metadata>  
    <o:viewParam name="entrega_id" value="#{rotaEntregaBean.id_entrega}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{rotaEntregaBean.inicializar}" />
</f:metadata>
```

**Função JS**

```
function initMap(xhr, status, args) {   
    var qtd_entregas = args.coord.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < args.coord.length; i++) {
        waypts.push({
            location : args.coord[i].latitude + ', ' + args.coord[i].longitude,
            stopover : true,
        });
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode executar o JS dentro do seu bean. Chame a função assim que terminar de preencher seu array. Para executar dentro do bean é assim:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("testeJS();");
```

Comment: Eu tentei desse jeito, mas como eu vou passar o vetor por parâmetro para a função JS que estou chamando?